# PHP new lines in CodeIgniter controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, error-handling, newline

Can anyone see an error with the following line of code from a CodeIgniter controller script - it's part of an email script.

The "\n" do not appear as new lines in the email - just the "\n" raw code itself:

```
$this->email->message($_POST['name'] 
        . " \n" . $_POST['email'] . " \n" . $_POST['message']);
```

They are enclosed in double-quotes, so I don't see what the issue would be...

Comment: I don't think \n parses here. Try a break tag instead

Comment: Looks fine to me, whats the content type on the email?

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same thing you are trying to do (Successfully) like this:

```
$msg="
Name: ".$this->input->post('name')."
Email: ".$this->input->post('email')."
Message: ".$this->input->post('message');
$this->email->message($msg);
```

Hope it helped you. If there is any problem, Comment.